# Using Postgres (and AWS Redshift) DB Link with JOOQ

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq, dblink

We are trying to establish a DB link between Postgres and AWS Redshift DB (which isn't a problem) but we are using [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/) to construct DB Query for the same.

**What is working?** We are able to write JOIN SQL queries for the data we want to fetch perfectly fine if the two tables were in the same database. For example, if we have a query:

```
SELECT somefields
FROM dblink('global_database'::text, '
SELECT
    ... some data selected...) t1(username text, location int, createdAt timestamptz)
         JOIN user_meta t2 on "userId" = t1.userId
    AND createdAt between ... some date range ...
WHERE ...'
GROUP BY ...
ORDER BY ... DESC;
```

Now we are constructing the query with JOOQ:

```
Query query = dslContext
                .select(somefields))
                .from(table(TABLE))
                .rightJoin(TABLE_TWO).on(getJoinOnCondition())
                .where(whereCondition)
                .groupBy(groupByFields)
                .orderBy(orderByFields)
                .limit((int) pageRequest.getPageSize());
```

How to establish the DB link in the JOOQ Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in 2 steps:

- Generate code for both of your databases separately. Make sure the Redshift tables don't have a schema associated with them, using `<outputSchemaToDefault>true</outputSchemaToDefault>`, [see the manual](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-catalog-and-schema-mapping/)
- Whenever you use a dblink, wrap your Redshift table in a [plain SQL template](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) when you put it in the `FROM` clause, and use the generated class otherwise, using e.g. the below utility:

```java
static Table<?> dblink(String conn, Table<?> table, Field<?>... fields) {
    return table("dblink({0}, {1}) as {2}({3})",
        inline(conn),
        inline(DSL.using(POSTGRES).render(select(fields).from(table))),
        table.getUnqualifiedName(),
        list(
            Stream.of(fields)
                  .map(f -> DSL.sql("{0} {1}",
                       f.getUnqualifiedName(),
                       sql(f.getDataType().getCastTypeName())
                  ))
                  .toArray(QueryPart[]::new)
        )
    );
}
```

The usual static import is implied:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

And then use this utility like this:

```java
Query query = dslContext
                .select(somefields))
                .from(dblink("global_database", TABLE, TABLE.fields()))
                .rightJoin(TABLE_TWO).on(getJoinOnCondition())
                // You can now use TABLE as if it were a local table
                .where(whereCondition)
                .groupBy(groupByFields)
                .orderBy(orderByFields)
                .limit((int) pageRequest.getPageSize());
```

Comment: Not sure where you constructed the Redshift query separately. The main part which I do not understand is `.from(dblink("global_database", TABLE, TABLE.fields()))`. This just specifies the DB Link name, table reference and fields. Where do we put the actual query, with possible WHERE clause in it?

Comment: @ShubhamA.: I showed you the definition of the `dblink()` method. Look at it, it's all there. It uses a [plain SQL template](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/)